# Why can’t I still get IIS ApplicationPoolIdentity to write a file to folder?

Tags: asp.net, file-io, iis-7.5, ntfs, applicationpoolidentity

My ASP-Webpages application needs to write self-generated files to a local folder under its root directory. Everything runs like a charm on- and from my development environment, even to any other given network locations. 
The problem is that I can’t get the production environment to do the same. Just no files get created, anywhere. Nor are any exceptions thrown on missing permissions etc. Nada.

I believe I’ve read and tried out just about everything anyone had written on the Internet over the past seven years and I feel like I’m chasing my own behind trying to solve this problem. Should it be really that difficult?
At the risk of getting marked as duplicate I see no other option than to post my question here..

Basically, here is what I have this far:

The production application runs on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS version 7.5. It has a dedicated Application Pool, with its identity set to ApplicationPoolIdentity (.NET Framework v4 / Integrated pipeline).
[Application Basic Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPOUs.png)

Verified AppPool membership of IIS_IUSRS.
[Verified Group Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDYnn.png)

User Authentication is set to Windows Authentication. 
[User Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UslcZ.png)

Should Anonymous Authentication be set to ‘Enabled’ to get the ApplicationPoolIdentity be used? I’ve tried setting it on, but it conflicts with the Windows Authentication, which is an essential part of our application and cannot be switched off.
If so, then how?

Both the Application Pool and the IIS_IUSRS have been granted Read & Write permissions on the folder.
I’ve tried setting Full control, but that didn’t help either.
[Folder Security Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjL2N.png)

Here is the (stripped down) code that writes the files to the desired location: 
[Stripped-down Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPao7.png)

Other (silly) things I’ve tried are:

- Playing around with absolute and relative path directions in my code.
- Enabling Anonymous Authentication, resulting in a conflict with the necessary Windows Authentication.
- Set Application Pool ProcessModel identity to Network Service.
- Recycle Application Pool.
- Load User Profile ‘On’ for the Application Pool.
- Setting IE Enhanced Security Configuration ‘Off’ for users.
- Restarting server machine.
- Using different browsers.
- Give 'everyone' full folder permissions, just to try the effects, nothing..
- Set AuthenticatedUserOverride to UseWorkerProcessUser via IIS Configuration Editor. This causes that my application doesn't recognise Current.User.Identity.Name anymore, so it blocks further site access.

What I need is to keep Windows Authentication, but also be able to have the application anonymously write files to a given location.

Can anybody please hint me in the right direction or just tell me what I’ve overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of drive is drive E? Mapped drive from another machine?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. Drive E is the physical home of our webapp, so: E:\Websites\aTestSite\troubleFolder.. It's located on a virtual machine in our domain, from which IIS runs.